# How do you solve a differential equation with a delta function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I was solving for an electrical circuit and wound up with this equation: $10di/dt +10i -24\delta(t) = 0$

How do you solve this? Laplace transform?

Comment: Laplace Transform works. The Laplace Transform of the delta function is $1$. See: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iii-fourier-series-and-laplace-transform/laplace-transform-basics/MIT18_03SCF11_s27_5text.pdf

Comment: How? I forgot sorry

Comment: With the Laplace transform you find $10(s I(s)-i(0))+10I(s)-24=0$ so that $I(s)=\frac{24+10i(0)}{10s+10}$, which can be inverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the integrating factor $e^t$ for $i'(t)+i(t)$ you get
$$
(e^ti(t))'=2.4·e^t·δ(t)=2.4·δ(t)
$$
as $e^0=1$. Thus
$$
e^ti(t)-i(0)=2.4·H(t)\iff i(t)=(i(0)+2.4·H(t))·e^{-t}
$$